# Django - oscar show a field in dashboard

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-oscar

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct
from oscar.core.compat import AUTH_USER_MODEL
from django.db import models

class Product(AbstractProduct):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True)

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

I added this code to forked catalog model > 
I want to show it in the dashboard,[Image of dashboard and dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqEIE.png) I tried admin.site.register but it is not working.

This is the code for override of form , when I fork and overrtide it doesn't work but when I change the code in core it works .

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.forms import ProductForm

from oscar.core.loading import get_class, get_classes, get_model
from yourappsfolder.catalogue.models import Product

class SellerField(ProductForm):

    class Meta(ProductForm.Meta):

        model =Product


        fields = [
            'title','seller', 'upc', 'description', 'is_public', 'is_discountable', 'structure']
```

Comment: You need to override the corresponding dashboard form: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/dashboard/catalogue/forms.py#L171

Comment: @solarissmoke I did fork it, I added the code to the question, it works when I edit the core, but it is not working when I fork(it reads and no error ), the app is also installed in Settings and removed the  #'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forked the form incorrectly. Calling your form class `SellerField` will not work. The form class needs to have exactly the same name as the core form, otherwise Oscar's loader will not find it. Change it like this:

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.forms import ProductForm as BaseProductForm

class ProductForm(BaseProductForm):
    class Meta(BaseProductForm.Meta):
        fields = ['title','seller', 'upc', 'description', 'is_public', 'is_discountable', 'structure']
```